# Are file permissions and owner:group properties included in git commits?

Tags: git

Are file permissions and owner:group properties included in git commits?
How are these properties of files and directories handled throughout the git pipeline [commit, push, pull, merge, etc] ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Files in Git are assigned either 644 (owner `rw-`, group and other `r--`) or 755 (owner `rwx`, group and other `r-x`). Ownership information is not stored.

This is deliberate, and well-explained by [this post](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/why-not-preserve-file-permissions-tp1619926p1620446.html) by Git's maintainer, Junio Hamano:

> Actually in a very early days, git used to record the full (mode & 0777) 
>   for blobs.
>
> Once people started using git, everybody realized that it had a very 
>   unpleasant side effect that the resulting tree depended on user's umasks, 
>   because one person records a blob with mode 664 and the next person who 
>   modifies the file would record with mode 644, and it made it very hard to 
>   keep track of meaningful changes to the source code.  This issue was fixed 
>   long time ago with commit e447947 (Be much more liberal about the file 
>   mode bits., 2005-04-16).

Answer (score 3):

Generally, no. These are all things that are local to particular machine environment.

The exception is that Git uses permission-like settings to track a few "universal" attributes, like whether a file is executable and if an object is file or a submodule. Git can, where possible, map these to your local environment on checkout.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, no, but *nix will push changes in permissions.  I've had problems where Windows see changes in *nix permissions and isn't quite sure what to do with it.