# How do you see file permissions in Github?

Tags: github

How can you see the file permissions set on a file in Github via the web interface?

I don't see an option to display this information, but it seems like it must be available.

Answer (score 7):

Git [only tracks the executable bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800349/are-file-permissions-and-ownergroup-properties-included-in-git-commits/29800979#29800979).

GitHub displays this information in the box header when opening a file:

[image: github executable bit]