# How do I see the permission of a file in Git?

Tags: git

I'd like to see the file permission as it exists in the repository index.

How can this be done?

Comment: git does actually track the executable bit

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use [`git ls-files -s <file>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#git-ls-files--s):

> Show staged contents' mode bits, object name and stage number in the output.

Note that Git [only tracks files' executable bit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29800979/354577). You'll only ever see 644 or 755.

Answer (score 12):

[`ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files):

> Show information about files in the index and the working tree
>   **`--stage`** : Show staged contents' mode bits, object name and stage number in the output.

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 b5ff1408aca94e2f33b9af9299b38764c2ec0bb7 0       .editorconfig
100644 4ef3204cd0928c0460274208c40a9e63b6c58beb 0       .gitignore
```

File mode is the last 3 digits of the first number. (see [index-format](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6867272d5b5615bd74ec97bf35b4c4a8d9fe3a51/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt#L63))

Comment: is there a command to only see about one file and not sift through all of the files outputted by ls-files --stage

Comment: Yes, with `git ls-files --stage YOUR_FILE` as shown in the accepted answer.