# Running an executable on Heroku upon Flask API endpoint access

Tags: git, heroku

I am working on a Web API that uses Flask with Python to provide functionality that is provided by an executable file. The setup works locally but I want to set up the Web API on Heroku.

I am running into an issue with the fact that executable files that I push along with the code do not have permission to execute. I cannot use `chmod +x <executable>` since the moment the dyno is destroyed the permissions are reset.

Alternative ways to deploy the Web API are also welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Git [tracks the executable bit of files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29800979/354577). You should be able to make the file executable locally, then commit and redeploy:

```
chmod +x <executable>
git add <executable>
git commit -m "Set executable bit on <executable>"
git push heroku
```

Though if it is available via an Ubuntu package you'll be better served by not tracking it at all and installing it via [the Apt buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt).

There may be other options as well, but without more information about what `<executable>` is and where it comes from it's hard to suggest the right solution.